# Socket.IO and http concurrency

Tags: http, server, socket.io, client

In our app, we're using socket.io to get realtime notification.

Before connecting to the socket, we first get all of our previous notifications with a http request and then connect with the socket.

The problem was then what happen if a notification is created in the time between the end of the http answer and the connection to the socket.

But in fact, even if we connect the socket before get all of our notifications. If we don't have any possibility to get the status of the http answers, we can't know if it possiblity contains a notification received in the socket, example with our socket to get the number of notifications.

```
--> connecting to the socket

--> http get notifications number

<-- new notification emit in socket

<-- http answer of the notification number
```

How do you know if the http answer contains the new notification ?

is there a name for this "paradox" ?

Maybe we don't get it right and should use a different pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to solve a race condition like this is to have some identifying tag in each notification.  The most common one is a tag number that increases with each notification or a time/date stamp (but you may want to make sure you don't get dups with the same time/date stamp).

Then, you can connect with socket.io and it will send you a message with the current last tag number.  You can then do an http request or a socket.io message (either one will work) that asks for all messages from the last tag number and earlier (a type of query).  Then, you know that you will get all the messages reliably.

So, the sequence of events would be this:

1. Connect on socket.io
2. Server sends you over socket.io the last timestamp used
3. You send message to the server asking for all messages from last timestamp and earlier
4. Server sends you all messages from last timestamp and earlier
5. Server sends client any new messages as they are created

It's possible to combine steps 2-4 so the server automatically sends you all earlier messages as soon as you connect, but you have to make sure this doesn't happen on an auto-reconnect when the existing web page already has all those messages.  If you wanted to implement that auto-send behavior, you could use a query parameter on the socket.io connect that tells the server you want it to send you messages that arrived before your connection.